# How can I import zip code into Google Spreadsheet from Google Maps XML api via =importxml("URL","xpath") function

Tags: xml, google-maps, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to get the zip code out of the google maps API with into a Google Spreadsheet.

I am using the `=importxml("URL","xpath")` function to parse the API response.

Yet it is not working. When I try to parse the ZIP code out of following API call

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Via+S.+dell'Uomo,+26+Milano
```

I am using following formula

```
=importxml(B2,"//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[9]/long_name/")
```

I have an example in the following sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zLP6yShUcwdnyHD3QZvhjkEePkXvn1zsF6pop2s-CDA/edit?usp=sharing

Instead of returning me the zip code, I get an error:

```
Error
Imported Xml content can not be parsed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For root node you always use one slash "/".
Double Slash "//" is known as wildcard path which (in essence) returns all nodes that matches the name specified and in case of root node, its always one and absolute for any given XML.

In your case I assume you want address_component[9] as absolute value. Therefore your query should look like below:

```html
"/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[9]/long_name")
```

**Note:** When I tested I got zip code in address_component[8] and I tested the xpath with the same as well, which works.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/index#ParsingXML)'s official Google docs for XML parsing.

**EDIT**: To answer your question in the comment:

```html
/GeocodeResponse/result//address_component[type/text() = 'postal_code']/short_name/text()
```

Above query returns this result (for a test query): *Text='20129'*

Cheers!

Comment: I tried that at the beginning and found my mistake, thank you for bringing me on the right track. As the quantity of address components changes frequently depending on the request, it's not possible with to get the ZIP reliably via =importxml(). Do you have any other idea to archive it?

Comment: Instead of getting zip code by absolute value of address_component[] get it as a text string and print the name. The documentation I referred to has further explanation. Just get all `//address_component` then get `/postal_code` string and print `/long(or short)_name`.